# Is there an alternate way of using apply lambda here?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dictionary, and want to create a new column which references this dict:

```
df['new'] = df['new'].apply(lambda x: dict.get(x))
```

.apply is notorious for being slow, is there a way of doing this operation and still taking advantage of numpy vectorization speed?

Answer (score 1):

Use  [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

> map accepts a dict or a Series. Values that are not found in the dict
> are converted to NaN, unless the dict has a default value (e.g.
> defaultdict):

```
df['new'] = df['new'].map(my_dict)
```